# Install Manager Application in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6

I got a windows 2003 and a slim tomcat 6 installation with several application running.
Now I want to "install" the manager application to refresh certain apps...

I copied the manager folder of another installation into the webapps folder an restarted the tomcat. I checked out that there are manager.xml files in all folder of conf/Catalina/... (automaticly generated??)

Still I get a 404

Comment: Anything in the Catalina logs about failing to start the webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
The Catalina log point me to a wrong version of the servlet-api.jar for the manage app.
So I did an "open heart operation" and downloaded the source of ne newest tomcat Version an replaced all in the lib an bin folder.

This is a bad anwser, but for me it worked...

Thanks Shane